# Search Method not working

Tags: java, hashmap

Basically i have a hashmap and the search method is missing a keyboard.next which should allow the user to input the name they want to search for.  There are no errors.  The output does not allow an opportunity for the user to enter the name they want to search.  The weird thing is i can use the userInput method and it works perfectly.  Here is my code:
Store declaration

```
//Imports.
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************  
public class MainApp
{
    //The Scanner is declared here for use throughout the whole MainApp.
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();

    }
    public void start()
    {
//Create a Store named Store and add Employee's to the Store.
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));
//********************************************************************      

/*Test Code.
        Store.searchByName("James O' Carroll");
        Store.print();
        Store.searchByEmail("gmail.com");
        Employee andy = Store.searchByEmail("hotmail.com");
        System.out.println(andy);
        Employee employee = Store.searchByName("James O' Carroll");
        if (employee != null)
        {
            employee.setEmployeeName("Joe");
            employee.setEmployeeId(1);
            employee.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
           Store.edit(employee);
           Store.print();
        }*/
//********************************************************************      

        int choice ;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Company Database.");
        do
        {
         choice = MenuMethods.getMenuChoice(
                "1.\tView All" +
                "\n2.\tAdd" +
                "\n3.\tDelete" +
                "\n4.\tDelete All " +
                "\n5.\tEdit" +
                "\n6.\tSearch" +
                "\n7.\tPrint"+
                "\n8.\tExit", 8, "Please enter your choice:", "Error [1,8] Only");
         //String temp = keyboard.nextLine();  This prevented entering the choice.
        switch (choice) 
        {
            case 1:
                 System.out.println("View All");
                Store.print();

                break;

        case 2:
             System.out.println("Add");
                Employee employee = MenuMethods.userInput();
                Store.add(employee);

                break;

        case 3:
             System.out.println("Delete");
                //Store.delete();


                break;

        case 4:
                System.out.println("Delete All");
                Store.clear();

                break;
        case 5:
           System.out.println("Edit");
           Employee employee2 = MenuMethods.userInput();
           Store.searchByName(employee2.getEmployeeName());
         if (employee2 != null)
        {
            employee2.setEmployeeName("Joe");
            employee2.setEmployeeId(1);
            employee2.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
           Store.edit(employee2);
           Store.print();
        }

            break;
        case 6:
             System.out.println("Search");
             Employee employee1 = MenuMethods.userInputByName();
             Store.searchByName(employee1.getEmployeeName());


            break;
        case 7:
             System.out.println("Print");
            Store.print();

            break;
        case 8:
             System.out.println("Exit");

            break;
        }


        } while (choice != 8);

     }
}

//Imports
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************

public class MenuMethods 
{
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



    //Methods for the Company Application menu.
    //Method for validating the choice.
         public static int getMenuChoice(String menuString, int limit, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
         {
                System.out.println(menuString);
                int choice = inputAndValidateInt(1, limit, prompt, errorMessage);
                return choice;
         }
    //********************************************************************
    //This method is used in the getMenuChoice method.
            public static int inputAndValidateInt(int min, int max, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
            {
                int number;
                boolean valid;
                do {
                    System.out.print(prompt);
                    number = keyboard.nextInt();
                    valid = number <= max && number >= min;
                    if (!valid) {
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                } while (!valid);
                return number;
            }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInput()
    {
         String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee ID:");
         int employeeId = keyboard.nextInt();
         temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee E-mail address:");
         String employeeEmail  = keyboard.nextLine();
         return e = new Employee(employeeName , employeeId, employeeEmail);

    }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInputByName()
    {

         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");

         return e =  new Employee(employeeName);

    }
    //********************************************************************



}
```

Search Method in the mainApp

```
case 6:
             System.out.println("Search");
             Employee employee1 = MenuMethods.userInputByName();
             Store.searchByName(employee1.getEmployeeName());


            break;
```

The actual Search method.

```
public Employee searchByName(String employeeName) 
    {
        Employee employee = map.get(employeeName);    
        System.out.println(employee);
        return employee;
    }
//********************************************************************
```

The userInputByName method.  This is where the problem seems to lie.

```
 public static Employee userInput()
    {
         String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee ID:");
         int employeeId = keyboard.nextInt();
         temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee E-mail address:");
         String employeeEmail  = keyboard.nextLine();
         return e = new Employee(employeeName , employeeId, employeeEmail);

    }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInputByName()
    {

         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");

         return e =  new Employee(employeeName);

    }
    //********************************************************************
```

Comment: could you please post the code where you initialize the map (mainApp)?

Comment: is your question that you cannot input the name of employee when using `userInputByName()` but it works if using `userInput()`?

Comment: actually it's hard to figure out the problem with your posted code. I suggest you post your mainApp and `MenuMethods` classes. Because I see `keyboard` is an instance variable of `EmployeeStore` but it is used within `userInput()` and `userInputByName()` which are methods of `MenuMethods`.

Comment: ok no problem i will edit them in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try my best.

First of all, why is there two `println` statements in your `userInputByName()`?

```
 public static Employee userInputByName()
    {
         Employee e = null; 
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:"); //!???

         return e =  new Employee(employeeName);
    }
```

Then, in the case `6`, you just call the method `searchByName` and does not check if the search is successful or not. I suggest:

```
case 6:
    System.out.println("Search");
    Employee employee1 = MenuMethods.userInputByName();
    Employee foundEmployee = Store.searchByName(employee1.getEmployeeName());

    if (foundEmployee != null) {
        System.out.println("Found employee!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Found!");
    }

    break;
```

Comment: the two prints were just to see if it actually went by the keyboard call.

Comment: it still skips the keyboard.  Visually it looks the exact same as the UserInput method so i dont understand how it can be running like that.